# how to create a button when the first element is clicked it should hide and show second element using ng-show/ng-hide angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

please help, how to make show/hide when the first element is clicked, the first element will be changed into second element by using angularjs ng-show/ng-hide?

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-click="showDetails1 = !showDetails1">
     <div ng-show="showDetails1">
          //this is element 1
     </div>
     <div ng-click="showDetails2 = !showDetails2">
          <div ng-show="showDetails2">
              //this is the second element that will appear when the first element is clicked
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to show element 2 when element 1 is hidden and show element 1 when element 2 is hidden.

```
   <div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="showDetails =true" ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails">
         <div ng-show="showDetails">
              //this is element 1
         </div>
         <div ng-show="!showDetails">
              //this is the second element that will appear when the first element is clicked
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-click="showDetails1 = !showDetails1">
     <div ng-show="showDetails1">
          //this is element 1
     </div>
     <div ng-hide="showDetails1">
          //this is the second element that will appear when the first element is clicked
      </div>
</div>
```